# Rewrite one main page to 404 but not other ones

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following three rewrite rules which direct users off to payment forms based on what user they are which works fine:

```
RewriteRule ^/marketing/staff$ https://www.example.com/marketing/payroll/forms/salary-payment-form.shtml?stafftype=EXAMPLE [R,L]

RewriteRule ^/marketing/other-staff$ https://www.example.com/marketing/payroll/forms/salary-payment-form.shtml?stafftype=HR [R,L]

RewriteRule ^/marketing/other2-staff$  https://www.example.com/marketing/payroll/forms/salary-payment-form.shtml?stafftype=EXAMPLE\ Commercial\ Ltd [R,L]
```

I want to put in a rule so that if someone just goes to the main url they will just get a 404 - I have tried adding the url below but its not working:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/marketing/payroll/forms/salary-payment-form.shtml$
RewriteRule ^/marketing/payroll/forms/salary-payment-form.shtml$ - [R=404,L]
```

When I put this in the all the above urls are getting 404 - how do I restrict it so that JUST the main url above gives a 404 and not the ones which redirect to specific pages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (`%{QUERY_STRING}` is not part of `%{REQUEST_URI}`):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/marketing/payroll/forms/salary-payment-form.shtml$ - [R=404,L]
```